# Adding items to dictionary by key

Tags: dictionary, swift3

I have different keys and items to add to a dictionary:

```
City + Berlin
City + London
City + New York City
Movie + Horror
Movie + Science-Fiction
Movie + Thriller
Food + Burger
Food + Vegetables
Food + Ice Cream
Sports + Baseball
Sports + Soccer
Sports + Tennis
Technology + Apple
```

I want the matching keys to be one key and the values as an array matching that one key like this:

```
City: [Berlin, London, New York]
Movie: [Horror, Science-Fiction, Thriller]
etc.
```

Every pair (one key + matching values) should be together in one UICollectionViewCell.

I have searched for creating and accessing a dictionary, but I just cannot find the right solution for this.

Thank you!

Comment: So you want to have a Dictionary where keys are Strings and values are Arrays of Strings? Where is your data coming from? Without more context, all you could get is how to hardcode such a Dictionary, but I guess that wouldn't be so useful...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each of the items you show are strings, you need to declare a dictionary of type `[String: [String]]` (key is type `String` and value is an array of `String`)

```
let dictionary = [
    "City": ["Berlin", "London", "New York"],
    "Movie": ["Horror", "Science-Fiction", "Thriller"],
    // ...etc.
]
```